# Doing select_related() twice - using the output queryset

Tags: django

I am trying to join two models together.

Project has an FK to org (orgid)
People has an FK to org (orgid)

But, I want the result of org + project + people,

So I tried to do select_related() and then select_related on the outcome to join the new queryset to the other model.

It didn't work :(

```
a = people.objects.filter(personid=user, status='approved').select_related('orgid')
b = a.select_related('projectid')
```

I need the join of these two essentially

```
a = people.objects.filter(personid=user, status='approved').select_related('orgid')
b = project.objects.filter(orgid__in=t, orgid=orgid).select_related('orgid')
```

In SQL this would be simply

```
SELECT * from(
SELECT app_org.orgid as orgid, orgname, username, role from app_org
LEFT JOIN app_people on app_people.orgid = app_org.orgid)x
LEFT JOIN app_project in x.orgid = app_project.orgid
```

Can anyone please help me?

I also tried

```
a = people.objects.filter(personid=user, status='approved').select_related('orgid__projectid')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship you're following, from org_id to a Project, is a reverse foreign key, so you'll need to use prefetch_related, with the suffix _set unless you have a related name on the relationship.

```
a = (people.objects
    .filter(personid=user, status='approved')
    .select_related('orgid')
    .prefetch_related('orgid__project_set')
    )
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your comment - I had not known about '_set'. However, I am getting a bit of an error: Cannot find 'projectid' on org object, 'orgid__projectid' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()

Comment: try simply project_set.  I might have got the _id from your q

Comment: Thanks so much! This seems to work without error. I can access the person and org attributes, but trying to select project fields returns nothing. With org, I had to do orgid.orgid, with project, I tried projectid.projectid, but no luck!

Comment: Ah yeah I have checked and it hasn't done either of the joins that way

Comment: try orgid.project_set.all - there may be multiple projects per org so you'll need to loop through them (also fixed a typo in select_related)

Comment: Hmm... I don't get it! No errors but when I look at the full list of fields it hasn't joined project :(

Comment: How are you looking at the full list? Presumably you are sure the org in question has projects.

Comment: In the end I used a raw sql query, it's probably not as efficient but I couldn't get it to work. I really appreciate the help - reverse lookups is something new I've learned about!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your model, but i think it should works:

```
query = people.objects.filter(personid=user, status='approved').select_related('org','org__project')
```